# Can I build a very simple Google Cloud Messaging backed Android application without any server-side code?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to build a GCM backed application for Android and so far it's going quite well. It's really simple and all I'm trying to achieve is to allow the user to push some messages from his computer to his device.

Once the user calls [`register`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#register%28java.lang.String...%29), he gets a registration id which is persisted in the shared preferences. He can email this registration key to himself which he saved on his computer allowing the computer to push notifications to him.

From what I've read, registration ids may expire at some intervals and it is wise to call `register` again. The docs for GCM in-turn say:

> Register the application for GCM and return the registration ID. You
>   must call this once, when your application is installed, and send the
>   returned registration ID to the server.
>
> Repeated calls to this method will return the original registration
>   ID.

Do the registration keys change for the same application on the same device? If so, do I still need a server to manage and constantly update these registration keys? (If that is the case: it feels clumsy that I need to write an AppEngine backend as well to manage their constantly-updated registration keys and I can't seem to understand the rationale for such an implementation.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The server side's purpose is much more than keeping the registration ID of a single device, as you describe in your case. It is used to maintain a DB of multiple registration IDs, and can decide when to send messages to them and what those messages would contain.

In your simple case it doesn't seem like you need a server side (assuming emailing the registration ID is a good enough solution for your purposes). The registration ID doesn't change often (in my experience), and even if it does, you can always re-send it the same way you intend to send it the first time.

Comment: Working with the registration id is more than good enough for me. The first time, the user installs the application. He can email the registration key to himself and use that in his computer. I just toyed around with my application a bit and it seems that calling `register` always returns a different key while the documents say otherwise. It also seems that when sending a GCM message to the server, the GCM server responds with the new registration key of the device, just one which you have to save. If you don't save it and use that in future requests, the GCM messages won't go through.

Comment: The issue is that I haven't found all these issues documented anywhere. Most of the GCm documents speak on a very macro level and I've gotten confused. Thanks Eran.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla I haven't encountered this constant change of Registration ID, but I tested it before the new API was introduced, so perhaps now they change more often. However, the old registration ID seems to keep working for a long time after it's no longer the newest Registration ID (I never encountered a case where it stopped working). Anyway, in order for the app to be assigned a new Registration ID, it must explicitly register to GCM, so the app should always know what is its newest Registration ID.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the functionality to register device with GCM you can check function [isRegistered (Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#isRegistered%28android.content.Context%29)
This tells us whether or not application is Registered with GCM for push notifications

```
Do the registration keys change for the same application on the same device?
```

Yes, the registration id may change or expire

here is some code from Android documentation

```
int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
if (registeredVersion != currentVersion || isRegistrationExpired()) {
    Log.v(TAG, "App version changed or registration expired.");
    return "";
}
```

So it is always advisable to clear(invalidate) all registrations id's from your server once app is upgraded to new version and then register again

Comment: Doesn't the code that you posted apply to the older GCM library and not in the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` library?

Comment: I worked with GCM not new GoogleCloudMessaging library, yes this applies to GCM and I am not sure if it applies to new library as well

Comment: please paste the link to new library documentation I want to read that

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html